# inserting data into 2 tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am wondering how can I insert the values retrieved from a HTML form into 2 tables, loginDetails and memberDetails.

**loginDetails** (table_1 shown in the code)

loginID (PK) <-- auto increment

username

password

**memberDetails** (table_2 shown in the code)

memberID (PK) <-- auto increment

loginID (FK)

These are the codes I have so far, however the loginID in **memberDetails** table are always 0,:

PHP codes

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO $table_1 VALUES (NULL,
    '".$formValue['username']."',
    '".$formValue['password']."')";
if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query)) {
        $lastID = mysql_insert_id();
        $Query2 = "INSERT INTO $table_2 VALUES (NULL,
        '".$lastID."')";
        if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query2)) {
            $message = "You've sucessfully created the account!";
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'action'=>'login','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
        }
        else {
            $message = "Error occur in query2";
            echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "Error in query1";
        echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
    }
```

It would be great if this question can be solved, as i have been struggling in this for 3 nights already. Cheers.

Comment: Use `mysqli_insert_id($link)` instead of `mysql_insert_id`.

Comment: @MuntashirAkon i have tried this, but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @RyanVincent it is, because i am going to insert another table namely 'staffDetails' later on, which also contains loginID, which is foreign key associated with **loginDetails** table

Comment: @RyanVincent loginDetails is the parent, while member and staff are the child of loginDetails

Comment: @RyanVincent any suggestions towards this?

Comment: @JasonLau Did you include `$link`, because `mysqli_insert_id()` takes one parameter which is in your case `$link`.

Comment: @MuntashirAkon yes, i have included $link

Comment: That's strange. Anyway, have you tried the OOP way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can place your queries in an array. Loop through the array. If an error occurs, exit the script.

```
$myQueries = array(`"INSERT INTO $table_1 VALUES (NULL,
'".$formValue['username'].",
'".$formValue['password']."')",
  "INSERT INTO $table_2 VALUES (NULL,
    '".$lastID."')"
  )`;

 for($i = 0; $i < count($myQueries); $i++){
     if (mysqli_query($Link, $myQueries[$i])) {
           $lastID = mysql_insert_id();
            $message = "You've sucessfully created the account!";
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 
             'action'=>'login',
              'html'=>$message, 
              'console.log'=>$Query));
    }
    else {
        $message = "Error occur in query[$i]";
        echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error',
        'html'=>$message,                   
       'console.log'=>$Query));
        exit; // stops the next query
     }
    }
 }
```